# Laravel backpack crud for update and list with relationship

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-backpack, eloquent-relationship

I've got 2 tables with one to many relationship.

1. portfolios
   id
   category_id
   status
   image
2. portfolios_lang
   id
   portfolio_id
   title
   text
   lang

I used backpack crud for portfolios_lang and I was able to create records. I added my logic to store() in my PortfolioLangCrudController.
But when I want to update a record I can't make it so fields from portfolios were assigned depending on  portfolios_lang  I selected. Here is screenshot http://joxi.ru/L21x31Vt08aVgm

The same goes for list
http://joxi.ru/LmGP76vHleDbO2

I couldn't find anything in documentation. Is there a way to do those things?

EDIT

```
class PortfolioLangCrudController extends CrudController
{
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;

/**
 * Configure the CrudPanel object. Apply settings to all operations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setup()
{
    CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\PortfolioLang::class);
    CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/portfoliolang');
    CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('portfoliolang', 'portfolio_lang');
}

/**
 * Define what happens when the List operation is loaded.
 *
 * @see  https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-list-entries
 * @return void
 */
protected function setupListOperation()
{
    // CRUD::setFromDb(); // columns
    $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'portfolio_id', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Portfolio Id']);
    $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'category_id', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Category']);
    /* $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'category_id', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Category',
         'entity' => 'category',
         'model' => "App\Categories", // related model
         'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
     ]);*/
    $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'title', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Title']);
    $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'text', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Text']);
    $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'lang', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Lang']);

    $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'status', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Status']);

    $this->crud->setHeading('Portfolio', 'list');
    /**
     * Columns can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
     * - CRUD::column('price')->type('number');
     * - CRUD::addColumn(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']);
     */
}

/**
 * Define what happens when the Create operation is loaded.
 *
 * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-create
 * @return void
 */
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::setValidation(PortfolioLangRequest::class);

    $statuses = PortfolioLang::$statuses;
    $langs = Langs::getLangsArray();

    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'category_id', 'type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Category',
        'entity' => 'categories',
        'model' => "App\Categories", // related model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    ]);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'title', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Title']);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'text', 'type' => 'ckeditor', 'label' => 'Text']);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'lang', 'label' => 'Lang',
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'options' => $langs,
        'allows_null' => false,
        //'default' => 1,

    ]);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'portfolio_id', 'type' => 'hidden', 'label' => 'Portfolio']);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'status', 'label' => 'Status',
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'options' => $statuses,
        'allows_null' => false,
        'default' => 1,
    ]);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'image', 'type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Image',
        'crop' => true, // set to true to allow cropping, false to disable
       // 'aspect_ratio' => 1, // ommit or set to 0 to allow any aspect ratio
    ]);

    $this->crud->setHeading('Portfolio', 'create');

    //CRUD::setFromDb(); // fields

    /**
     * Fields can be defined using the fluent syntax or array syntax:
     * - CRUD::field('price')->type('number');
     * - CRUD::addField(['name' => 'price', 'type' => 'number']));
     */
}

/**
 * Define what happens when the Update operation is loaded.
 *
 * @see https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/crud-operation-update
 * @return void
 */
protected function setupUpdateOperation()
{

    CRUD::setValidation(PortfolioLangRequest::class);

    $statuses = PortfolioLang::$statuses;
    $langs = Langs::getLangsArray();

    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'category_id', 'type' => 'select', 'label' => 'Category',
        'entity' => 'categories',
        'model' => "App\Categories", // related model
        'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
    ]);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'title', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Title']);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'slug', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Slug']);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'text', 'type' => 'ckeditor', 'label' => 'Text',]);

    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'lang', 'label' => 'Lang',
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'options' => $langs,
        'allows_null' => false,
       // 'default' => 1,

    ]);


    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'portfolio_id', 'type' => 'hidden', 'label' => 'Portfolio']);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'status', 'label' => 'Status',
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'options' => $statuses,
        'allows_null' => false,
        'default' => 1,
    ]);
    $this->crud->addField(['name' => 'image', 'type' => 'image', 'label' => 'Image',
        'crop' => true, // set to true to allow cropping, false to disable
       // 'aspect_ratio' => 1, // ommit or set to 0 to allow any aspect ratio
    ]);


    $this->crud->setHeading('Portfolio', 'update');

    // $this->setupCreateOperation();
}


public function store(PortfolioLangRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    // var_dump($input['category_id']);

    $portfolios = new Portfolios();
    $portfolios->category_id = $input['category_id'];
    $portfolios->status = $input['status'];
    $portfolios->image = $input['image'];
    $portfolios->save();


    $portfolio_lang = PortfolioLang::where(
        'lang', '=', $input['lang']
    )->where('portfolio_id', '=', $portfolios->id)->first();

    if (empty($portfolio_lang)) {
        $portfolio_lang = new PortfolioLang();
    }
    $portfolio_lang->title = $input['title'];
    $portfolio_lang->text = $input['text'];
    $portfolio_lang->lang = $input['lang'];
    $portfolio_lang->portfolio_id = $portfolios->id;

    $portfolio_lang->save();
    return redirect('admin/portfoliolang');
}

public function update(PortfolioLangRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $portfolio_id = $request->input('portfolio_id');
    $portfolio_lang = PortfolioLang::where(
        'lang', '=', $input['lang']
    )->where('portfolio_id', '=', $portfolio_id)->first();

    if (empty($portfolio_lang)) {
        $portfolio_lang = new PortfolioLang();
    }
    $portfolio_lang->title = $input['title'];
    $portfolio_lang->text = $input['text'];
    $portfolio_lang->lang = $input['lang'];
    $portfolio_lang->portfolio_id = $portfolio_id;

    $portfolio_lang->save();
    return redirect('admin/portfoliolang');
}
}
```

EDIT 2
Thank you, I was able to show categories in list

```
 $this->crud->addColumn(['name' => 'portfolio_id', 'type' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Category', 'model' => "App\Categories",'attribute' => 'name','entity' => 'portfolio.category',
            'key'=>'categoryName']);
```

But is there no way I can edit related fields from one form?

Comment: please share PortfolioLangCrudController

Comment: @OMR, thank you for your reply. I added my PortfolioLangCrudController code in description

Comment: you mean you can not get status and category name in update and list operation?

Comment: @OMR, yes, I can't get all related fields. They are empty because I don't know how to assign them. If I update record from portfolio_lang , the related fields from portfolios are empty. I'm trying to do it from one form.

Comment: @OMR, I don't know what happened but your answer disappeared. I was able to show categories. Thank you very much)

Comment: your are welcome, I am glade that i can help, but you need to get more focus on the CRUD responsibilities, the main idea is, you can not update the portfolios state from  PortfolioLangCrudController, it is the responsibility of PortfolioCrudController